# Orthonormal basis in a cylindrical coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

So I am supposed to show if these vectors make an orthonormal basis in a cylindrical coordinate system.

$\vec e_p=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
cos(\theta )\\ 
sin(\theta )\\0 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr); \vec e_\phi=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-sin(\theta )\\ 
cos(\theta )\\0 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr); \vec e_z=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\1 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr);$

In order for a set of vectors to be an orthonormal basis they need to

1) have length one

2) be orthogonal to each other (dot product=0)

3) (be linearly independent. Not sure about this one)

To check the first point I used the dot product. I know that:

$\sqrt{<\vec u,\vec u>}=|\vec u|$

$\sqrt{<\vec e_p,\vec e_p>}=\sqrt{cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta)+0}=1$

$\sqrt{<\vec e_\phi,\vec e_\phi>}=\sqrt{sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)+0}=1$

$\sqrt{<\vec e_z,\vec e_z>}=\sqrt{0^2+0^2+1^2}=1$

Now i'll check the second point:

$<\vec e_p,\vec e_\phi>=-sin(\theta)cos(\theta)+sin(\theta)cos(\theta)+0\cdot1=0$

$<\vec e_p,\vec e_z>=cos(\theta)\cdot0+sin(\theta)\cdot0+0\cdot1=0$

$<\vec e_\phi,\vec e_z>=-sin(\theta)\cdot0+cos(\theta)\cdot0+0\cdot1=0$

Is my reasoning okay? Do I still have to show they are linearly independant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors are linearly independent if determinant of the matrix, composed by taking the vectors as columns in the matrix, is non-zero.

In other words:

$$\left|\begin{matrix}\cos \theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right| = 1 \neq 0,$$

so the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Interesting. That is much shorter than how I showed it. But why is it always true that the vectors are linearly independent if the determinant is non zero?

Comment: You can add any nonzero multiple of any row in a matrix to any other row in the matrix without changing the determinant.  If the vectors are linearly dependent, then there exists a set of operations that will allow you to replace one row with a row of zeros.  This will make the determinant zero.  This is equivalent to the statement that there exists $a_1, ... a_n$, not all zero, such that $\sum_1^n a_iV_i = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A set of nonzero, pairwise orthogonal vectors is always linearly independent, so you don't have to check that.